# Can't open Jira with local host

Tags: tomcat, localhost, jira

When I first launch Jira, it was on my localhost:8080. Once I closed Tomcat(I don't even know what that is), Jira left my localhost. How do I get it back on my localhost? I'm new to Jira.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the OS you've got Jira installed on:
[Atlassian Guide is here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/adminjiraserver/start-and-stop-jira-applications-938847802.html)

For Linux:

```
./bin/start-jira.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

If its windows 10, then go to C:\Users<user name>\Atlassian\Jira, run the batch file startup_bundled_jre , it will start running the Tomcat and then click on start_service in same folder i.e. batch.
After doing this, just start http://localhost:8080/ should start your JIRA or in same folder i.e. C:\Users<user name>\Atlassian\Jira, you will find Launch Jira in browser icon with defaulted to your default browser .

This should start your JIRA again.